# Like masked text, how to fill placeholders with text, and remove text to get back to placeholders?  

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, replace

I would like to be able to merge two (maybe three) strings as shown below.  Is this possible using a regex?  (The base language I am using is Actionscript 3.0, but I can work with a more generic regex solution.)

The idea is that `XYZ` (non-dash) chars are fixed in place, with the dashes getting replaced with the new chars, as needed.  Any additions are added as if a stack which skips around the fixed chars.  I imagine using a 3rd string: `---XYZ---` to maintain the placeholders.

### Re to comments

Masked text input is what I am looking for, but adding from the right rather than the left.  The underscores represent placeholders for added chars.  They will actually be seen on screen (unless replaced, of course).

An extensive example:

Preparation: set the string length: `---------`

Preparation: set the fixed: `---XYZ---`

Add char: `---XYZ--a`

Add char: `---XYZ-ab`

Add char: `---XYZabc`

Add char: `--aXYZbcd`

Add char: `-abXYZcde`

Add char: `abcXYZdef`

Remove char: `-abXYZcde`

Remove char: `--aXYZbcd`

Remove char: `---XYZabc`

Add multiple chars: `abcXYZmno`

Remove multiple chars: `---XYZabc`

### ANSWER

Based on @Charmander's suggestion, here is a complete example:

```
var carr:Array = [];

function fillMaskChars(maskText:String, chars:String, pop:Boolean = false):String
{
    var maskLen:int = maskText.match(/-/g).length;

    if (pop)
    {
        carr.pop();
    }
    else if (carr.length < maskLen)
    {
        carr = carr.concat(chars.split('', maskLen - carr.length));
    }

    if (carr.length == 0)
    {
        return maskText;
    }

    var i = carr.length - maskLen - 1;

    return maskText.replace(/-/g, function()
        {
            return carr[++i] || '-';
        });
}
```

Some tests:

```
var characters:String = "oed";
var curMask:String = "--W-RK---";

var outText:String = maskChars(curMask, characters);
trace(outText);

characters = "!";
outText = maskChars(curMask, characters);
trace(outText);

characters = "abcdefghij";
outText = maskChars(curMask, characters);
trace(outText);

outText = maskChars(curMask, "", true);
trace(outText);

outText = maskChars(curMask, "", true);
trace(outText);

outText = maskChars(curMask, "", true);
trace(outText);

outText = maskChars(curMask, "", true);
trace(outText);
```

Comment: A regex would not be too useful here, definitely not for a general solution (I can think of a few options, but a non regex solution seems better here). It looks like you're looking for a [masked input](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) control - I cannot find one for Actionscript (in 5 second in Google, but you can look harder `:)`).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean here. Could you provide more sample inputs and outputs, please?

Comment: What is the significance of the underscores? Their position is at the left, but when you add characters you add to the end of the string? The underscores do not seem like placeholders (if they were you would replace them at their current position).

Comment: @Kobi, I think I might accept a non-regex at this point.  I am not familiar with look-ahead or look-behind functionality, so if those offer a solution, then great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will find an array more appropriate. I'm afraid I have no experience in ActionScript, but it should not be difficult to translate from JavaScript.

```
function fillMaskWithCharacters(mask, characters) {
    var masked = mask.match(/-/g).length;
    var i = 0;

    return mask.replace(/-/g, function() {
        return characters[--i + masked] || '-';
    });
}
```

It is passed an array of characters, which you may manipulate as necessary. For example:

```
fillMaskWithCharacters('--w-rk---', ['!', 'd', 'e', 'o']); // "--worked!"
```

Comment: This is the right track.  (Javascript *should* work fairly seemlessly in AS3, as they are based on the same structure.  Back in 2010, Adobe was working with MS to make Javascript 2.0, but MS came out with Silverlight immediately after burning the collaboration.)  I have edited your post with forward version.

Comment: This doesn't help with removal, though, and I will think on a general solution following this method.

Comment: @iND: Sure it helps with removal. `pop()` items off the array, and call it again.

Comment: @iND: You don't need to use `substr(i, 1)`. `[i]` still works with strings. Also, you *can* just reverse the array and use `shift()` and `unshift()`. Finally, don't suggest edits to reply to a post.

Comment: @minitech, this is not designed to be used on an array, but on a AS3 `String`; so `pop()`, `shift()` and `unshift()` solutions on `Array`s unnecessarily increases overhead.  The `substr` correction limits the number of possible chars to the length of the mask, otherwise the insertion is incorrect.  Charmander said he did not know if it would work in AS3, so I think the edit was partially warranted; but your point is taken.

Comment: @iND: But the overhead is necessary if you want to remove characters, like you said - strings are immutable.

Comment: @minitech, your point is something to think about in terms of actual overhead.  There is conversion to `Array` initially, then the clipping (which may be handled better in `Array`s), then the insertion into a `String`.  I will have to do some real world testing for this.  Once there is a removal solution . . . just to point this out, the assembled text will be `pop()`-ed -- and not the input `Array` -- and *based on the mask*.

Comment: @iND: Hmm... based on the mask? I suppose you'll have to compare it against the original to restore the masked characters. Is there any way you could keep the array in the background instead, or something? (I don't know ActionScript, but that would be a great textbox feature if it existed `:)`)

Comment: @minitech, I have been thinking about using storage instead of programming.  Actually, that may be the best way: push/pop an independent `Array` (or `String`), and then run Charmander's corrected function.  There is actually a text masking feature in Adobe Flex, but incompatible without significant, unnecessary overhead.

Comment: This is not the correct solution, but it got me to *a* solution, so I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand why that should be very usful, but i guess this can be done with replace substring and lastindexof

```
var myChars:String = _abXYZcd;
var seperator:String = XYZ;

var stringToAdd:String = ee;

var pos:int = _myChars.lastIndexOf(seperator);
var newString = myChars.substring(0, pos) + myChars.substring( (pos+seperator.length), myChars.length)
newString += seperator;
newString += stringToAdd;
```

but i think it would be more useful to use an array or something.
like. Also i dont get if there should be limited characters, in that case all positions for replace and substring can be calculated only once... i didnt test it but i think you get the idea.

Comment: This is not quite right.  It maintains the underscore char at the beginning, and does not seem to build the result correctly.  Even if this were fixed to build it correctly, you would not have the underscore placeholders added back in, esp. when the results should be like `___XYZ_ab` or even `___XYZ___`.